# Can Office 2010 SP1 be installed without backup files?

Tags: installation, backup, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, service-pack

As title I'd like to know if it's possible to install SP1 without backup files - that is without the uninstall option.

Answer (score 1):

The patch itself does not say that you can (see screenshot), however, sometimes they are undocumented at patch level. You can try running it with the `/nobackup` switch.

[image]

Here is a list of Microsoft command line switches, but not all work for all programs or patches.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262841

Comment: I have actually confirmed that in this case, the /nobackup switch does not work.

Comment: Yes, this is not working. This is REALLY bad because guess what: files in `Updates` folder from the source media (updated with SP1) are copied in `C:\MSOCache`; plus a tons of files are copied in `C:\Windows\Installer`. Indeed i'm going to waste about 1Gb of space because i don't need to remove SP1.

Comment: Can you manually delete the files you don't need?